# getting video length of mov file with no audio error chrome js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

Is there an accurate way to determine the length of a .mov file with chrome? On our website we currently use `video.onloadedmetadata` but it's causing errors.

Example:

```
upload(data) {
 const file = data.body.get('file');
 const filename = file.name;

 const video = document.createElement('video');
 video.preload = 'metadata';
 video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
   const videoDuration = Math.floor(video.duration);
 }

 video.onerror = (error) => {
   debugger;
   console.error(error);
 };
};
```

**Image of error:**

[image]

Edit:
Meta data from video file, using command `exiftool post_131.1.1.mov > b.txt`

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.41
File Name                       : post_131.1.1.mov
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.0 MiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2022:04:21 15:48:44+10:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2022:04:26 10:14:37+10:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2022:04:26 09:52:14+10:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
File Type Extension             : mp4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.1
Compatible Brands               : isom, mp41, mp42
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2019:10:26 05:05:31
Modify Date                     : 2019:10:26 05:05:32
Time Scale                      : 600
Duration                        : 5.70 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 2
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2019:10:26 05:05:31
Track Modify Date               : 2019:10:26 05:05:32
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 5.70 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Image Width                     : 720
Image Height                    : 1280
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2019:10:26 05:05:31
Media Modify Date               : 2019:10:26 05:05:32
Media Time Scale                : 600
Media Duration                  : 5.70 s
Media Language Code             : und
Handler Type                    : Video Track
Handler Description             : Core Media Video
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : hvc1
Source Image Width              : 720
Source Image Height             : 1280
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Color Representation            : nclx 6 1 6
Video Frame Rate                : 20
Media Data Size                 : 2111343
Media Data Offset               : 2466
Image Size                      : 720x1280
Megapixels                      : 0.922
Avg Bitrate                     : 2.96 Mbps
Rotation                        : 0
```

Comment: That's not the error, that the error _object_, folded up so that we can't see anything meaningful. What's the actual error you get in the your console? (And remember not to use an image for that, just copy-paste the text and put it in code fences)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the comment. There is no error in the console, besides the `console.error(error);` inside the error function. Its a combination of no audio on the .mov file on chrome. I can provide a reproduction link if that will help

Comment: Only if it's tiny, and only _after_ you update the post to include what metadata is in the .mov file according to real video tools like ffmpeg or exiftool. Because .mov is just a container, and what matters is which audio and video codec are actually used, as not all codecs are universally supported. If there's no audio, the first thing to check if whether the file even uses codecs that are supported by browsers at all.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added metadata from exiftool above. Again really appreciate the help!

Comment: That compressor ID suggests it's an HEVC video, in which case [only Safari currently supports that](https://caniuse.com/hevc) (mostly because it's Apple's own format). You may simply need to those videos through an `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mov universal.mp4` pass before they'll play nice in (all) the browser(s).